# Build error resource directory not found

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'v created a new android project in vs 2013 and installed Android.Support.Library.v7.AppCompat package and dependencies. But when I build the project, I got an error that says

> resource directory
>   '[ProjectPath]\obj\Debug\resourcecache\B81A750477D10031D1844681B0F7EB17\res'
>   does not exist    file: [ProjectPath]\AAPT

- I'v cleaned the project
- reopen it
- rebuild it

but not help me.

Comment: Try to invalidate cache and restart. I think it was File -> invalidate cache and restart

Comment: @Jaco Thank you my friend, but i cant find this option in visual studio.

Comment: Hello Sahar Sarikhani, I strongly recommend you using Android Studio: It's awesome and it could help you

Comment: Delete obj\Debug folder

Comment: @Yuri-s I'v deleted it , but when build the project  , the folders recreated and the error appears

Comment: Can you add empty "res" folder to obj/Debug. Also, are you doing this in project path like MyProject or in MyProject.Droid?

Comment: @Yuri-s I also have done but still I get this error . My project path like MyProject.

Comment: Please do the same in MyProject.Droid

Comment: @Yuri-s How do I do this?

Comment: Just delete Debug folder in MyProject.Droid path from file explorer

Comment: @Yuri-s I do this, but my problem is not resolved :(

Comment: I see only one file in this folder - manifest. Can it be there is something wrong with your manifest? Is that the only error you are getting?

Comment: @Youri-s The project is empty and I'v just installed appcompat package . Manifest setting is default. Yes i get one error. I think this error related to m2repository files, but I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: why do you think it is about m2repository ?

Comment: Becuase at first i get some errors that say download and install m2repository , I'v manualy downloaded and copy it to extras folder of sdk, then I get some errors about java library and I did in accordance with the guidance of document in xamarin site. Copy folders in appdata / xamarin/ extra library/ version/ content, then I get this one error

Comment: I never heard about m2repository. I would suggest you to reinstall everything and preferably not manually but using installers

Answer (score -2):

I have encountered the same issue as you and have found a solution. I know this has been a long time since your post. Just put the solution here to help someone encounter similar issues.
My project can be built successfully previously, so this error must be caused by some kind of settings. A reasonable explanation and solution can be found in this link: http://smstuebe.de/2016/10/29/fix-android-app-compat/

This is caused by the incomplete Android SDK packages. The normal clean/rebuild won't help. Even if I reinstalled VS2015+Xamarin, I still have this issue.
So try the above solution if you came across similar issues.

Comment: I reinstall packages too , but not solved my problem.